# what is the difference and what does each of the functions exactly do? Why aren't they the same?

Tags: r, equation

polyEval should represent a polynomial equation. For example, polyEval(x = 2, a = c(2, 3, 1)) is supposed to return 12, whereas polyEval(1, c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)) is supposed to return 3. This is the case for the first polyEval function, but why isn't it for the second? What exactly is the second one doing wrong? Because in my understanding, they should work the same.

```
polyEval <- function(x,a) {
  n <- 1:length(a)
  return(sum(c(a[n]*x^(n-1))))
}

polyEval <- function(x,a) {
  sum(a*(x^(0:(length(a)))))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After correction, both raise `x` to the power 0, 1, 2, ..., length(a)-1 and then multiply the resulting vector by `a` and sum.

In the second one `length(a)` should be `length(a)-1`.

```
polyEval2 <- function(x,a) {
  sum(a*(x^(0:(length(a)-1))))
}

polyEval2(2, c(2, 3, 1))
## [1] 12

polyEval2(1, c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1))
## [1] 3
```